# How to use dynamic variables with Angular Translate Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using the gem angular-translate-rails and I'm trying to get the variables to passed to rails but it's not working. The backend is rails and the front end Angularjs.

So far this is what I've tried:

1.Within the controller:

```
$translate('analytics.show_review.directives.review_incomplete_message', {'number_of_not_empty_reviews': $scope.numberOfNotEmptyReviews,
  'number_of_reviews': $scope.numberOfReviews }).then(function (message) {
  $scope.reviewIncompleteMessage = message;
});
```

2.Translation yml:

```
en:
  home:
    message: "My variables are %{myFirstVariable} and %{ mySecondVariable }"
```

And I get an empty string in return
I tried  changing the combinations of camel case and snake case, but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variables in angular translate is this way

```
en:
  home:
    message: "My variables are {{ myFirstVariable }} and {{ mySecondVariable }}"
```

and for use it is like this

```
$translate('en.home.message', { myFirstVariable: 1, mySecondVariable: 2});
```